# Java: How to figure out whether .getInputStream() receives text or not?

Tags: java, sockets, methods, jtextfield

I'm programming chat tool. A JTextField reads the text, which I get by .getInputStream() from the client socket. But now I have to decide whether a new character is part of a message (string which sent to the socket) or the first character of a new message.

My recent idea is to figure out whether my .getInputStream()-method at the client socket is receiving text in one moment or not. Is there a method to find this out?

Comment: Do you have a button with an action listener attached that sends the text somewhere once it is entered or for that matter an action listener in general looking at your JTextField?

Comment: Yes, I have a 'send'-button with an action listener, but this one only sends the text to an IP and a port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending pure text, you could send a packet of data... send the size of the message string (as an encoded integer), followed by the message as text. Or, as subham says, just use a string encoding function to send whole strings at a time. That will do the buffering for you. You should use built-in functions to determine those boundaries rather than doing so yourself.

Comment: Nice idea! Now I end every message with (char)127, which cannot be represented in a JTextField, but it can be recognized and used for the condition of an if-loop in the 'receive'-method. Looks strange, but I like it and it definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

Create a output stream of the socket at the server and use the writeUTF() method to print the string on the socket. Thats all..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = is.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to make your proposed approach work reliably.  Basically, you cannot reliably distinguish the boundaries of the "messages" in a network stream because network congestion and the like will distort the packet arrival times, resulting in multiple (or partial) "messages" potentially being delivered in response to a `read(...)` call on the stream.

If you want a message structure to your protocol, you need to use something in the data stream itself to delineate the message boundaries.  For example, you could reserve a data value to mean "end of message", or prefix each message with a byte count.